# cosimplicial algebras to dg-algebras

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

The normalized [Moore complex](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Moore+complex) functor is usually considered taking [simplicial abelian groups](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+group) to [chain complex](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/chain+complex)es. But there is an obvious [dual version](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dold-Kan+correspondence#dual_doldkan_correspondence_13) that takes cosimplicial abelian groups to N-graded cochain complexes.

Moreover, applied on a cosimplicial group that has the structure of a cosimplicial ring, the Moore cochain complex yields a cochain complex that has the structure of a [dg-algebras](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dg-algebra) (the details are at [monoidal Dold-Kan correspondence](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+Dold-Kan+correspondence)).

This seems obvious and useful enough, but I find surprisingly little literature on this dual monoidal Dold-Kan correspondence. In fact the only relevant reference that I am aware of is Castiglioni-Cortinas, [Cosimplicial versus dg-rings: a version of the Dold-Kan correspondence](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0306/0306289v3.pdf).

They consider not the Moore cochain functor but its [right adjoint](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/right+adjoint), and show that its [left derived functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+functor) is an equivalence of [homotopy categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+category).

But it would seem that instead considering directly the Moore cochain complex functor on cosimplicial rings would be at least as interesting.

I can dream up some of its properties myself, but I keep feeling I must be missing the canonical literature on this, which must exist. Does anyone have more references on the Moore cochain complex functor on cosimplicial rings/algebras?

Comment: Hooray for lots of background links! +1

Answer (score 3):

This construction is closely related to de Rham cohomology, and used to compute the continuous cohomology of Lie groups.
This is part of the tools to compute Beilinson's regulator, as explained in

J. I. Burgos Gil, The regulators of Beilinson and Borel. CRM Monograph Series, 15. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2002.

See Chapter 7 for the abstract results, and Chapter 8 for its applications. (It seems that there is an online version [here](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=2&ved=0CBAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fatlas.mat.ub.es%2Fpersonals%2Fburgos%2Ffiles%2Fbrbr.pdf&rct=j&q=burgos+gil+math+beilinson&ei=uSIES8z2NJ_SjAf3-cy1AQ&usg=AFQjCNEDEBwjgreddwaUCOSp7SwTTnhWkw&sig2=rQ2lNRbJ8jyx1mPvHsOzQQ).)

The same kind of constructions is considered by Larry Breen and Bill Messing in

Combinatorial differential forms, Advances in Mathematics, vol. 164 (2001), 203-282

and used in this paper of Larry Breen [arXiv:0802.1833](http://fr.arxiv.org/abs/0802.1833) to study differential geometry on gerbes ("non-abelian de Rham cohomology").

Comment: What you list are indeed pretty much the examples that motivate the question. I talk about these examples in the example section here: http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Chevalley-Eilenberg+algebra

But what I have not seen in the literature much is a discussion of the general abstract property of this functor from cosimplicial algebras to dg-algebras. 

Thanks for the reference by Gil. I hadn't seen that before. Will have a look.

Comment: Burgos's book contains some abstract results: you might have a look at theorem 7.3 in Burgos's book (due to Beilinson), which gives a rather nice equivalence of categories between reduced dg algebras and "small" cosimplicial algebras.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yes, that section 7 is useful. Thanks. That smallness assumption in def 7.2 applies to some cases of interest, but is pretty restrictive. There should be a more general statement like this: while the dg-algebra NX corresponding to a cosimplicial algebra X need not be commutative, it is always an E-oo-algebra! So the full statement here should probably be that Dold-Kan induces an  oo-equivalence of E-oo algebra objects in cosimplicial abelian groups and E-oo algebra objects in N-graded cochain complexes. Have you seen anything like this stated?

Comment: For clarification: I am talking about the E-oo structure that is well known for cochains on simplicial sets (as here http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cochains+on+simplicial+sets#homotopycommutativity_7) . This should immediately generalize to all dg-algebras coming from cosimplicial algebras. Not just cosimplicial algebras of functions on a simplicial set.

Comment: Dear Urs, I stumbled across this thread while looking for a similar reference to the version of "E_infinity Dold-Kan" you mentioned... In particular, you might have already seen this paper by Richter: https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/richter/doldkan.pdf . That is the only type of reference I could find for a statement like this, did you find anything else similar in the literature?